# Probability of drawing cards infinitely

Tags: combinatorics

> For a Schnapsen deck (20 cards, with 4 suits, each suit containing Ace, Ten, King, Queen, Jack), 3 people A, B, C takes turns drawing a random card (starting from A -> B -> C), returning it to the deck and reshuffling the cards until a K heart or Q heart is drawn. The first one to draw one of these two cards wins.
>
> a) What's the probability of each outcome in the sample space? Show that they all add up to 1.
>
> b) Calculate the probability that A wins, B wins, C wins and no one wins.

For this question, I think the sample space will be infinite, since we can't be sure the 3 people can draw the right card each time.

The sample space will look like {W, LW, LLW, LLLW, ...}

Since each person will take a card and return it to the deck, each person has 2/20 chance of winning.

However, I don't know how to proceed from here! Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have to consider the probability of getting to draw.  A has a $\frac2{20}$ chance of winning on his first draw.  B's chance of winning on his first draw is only $\frac{18}{20}\cdot\frac{2}{20}$, because $2/2-$ of the time he doesn't even get to draw.

Comment: @saulspatz: Thanks! So the probability of A winning after some 3n, 3n+1, 3n+2 times is (18/20)^3n * 2/20, B winning is (18/20)^3n+1 * 2/20, and C winning is (18/20)^3n+2 * 2/20 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the sample space is infinite. The players may keep getting non-winning cards forever. To answer the first part, since the events are all mutually exclusive of each other the probability of all events will sum up to be $1$.

Now lets calculate the probability of $A$ winning. So either he wins his first try or he wins on the second try or he wins on the third try and so on till infinity-

$$\begin{align}P(A)&=\frac {2}{20}+\biggr(\frac {18}{20}\biggr)^3\frac {2}{20}+\biggr(\frac {18}{20}\biggr)^6\frac {2}{20}+\biggr(\frac {18}{20}\biggr)^9\frac {2}{20}\cdots\\
&=\frac {2}{20}\biggr(1+\frac {18}{20}^3+\frac {18}{20}^6\cdots\biggr) \\
&=\frac {2}{20}\Biggr({1\over 1-\bigr(\frac {18}{20}\bigr)^3}\Biggr) \\
&=\frac {1}{10}\times \frac {1000}{271} \\
P(A)&= \frac {100}{271}
\end{align}$$

Can you try to solve for P(B) and P(C) and P(none) similarly?

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help. If this has answered your doubt, you can accept this answer and close the question :)